# Derive date column based on current date and fixed start date

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following two columns:

```
date (datetime),
month_after_release (int)
```

These columns are filled monthly as part of an `incremental update`.

Let's say there was a release on Jan 1, 2015. This means we are currently in the 9th month after release `[formula: round off((current date - release date)/30,0)+1 = 9]` . So if I am now importing data with a current date (Sep 21, 2015), the two columns should be filled like this:

```
date = 2015-09-21 00:00:00.000
month_after_release = 9
```

In October, data which gets imported should then get the following information:

```
date = 2015-10-21 00:00:00.000
month_after_release = 10
```

How can I achieve this? One possibility which came to my mind would be to have a separate mapping table, which maps every single date to "month_after_release", but I was wondering if there is a better possibility?

The information when a release was is stored in a separate table, which looks like this:

```
ReleaseID,
Release_start_date
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? date/time is too often product specific, far from ANSI SQL.

Comment: You should clearly describe how you define "month", why is Sep 21, 2015 10 months after  Jan 1, 2015 and not 9?

Comment: I have added the necessary information and apologies for the typo. DBMS is SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2

Comment: It's usually best not to *store* data that can be calculated. By storing derived data, you introduce the possibility for it to be *inconsistent*.

Comment: Interesting. So what/where would be the right place to derive this data? Only as part of a view once the data has been processed into a cube or what is best practice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select releaseDate, DateDiff(MM, releaseDate, getdate()) MonthsSinceRelease
from table t
```

That's how you calculate it.